# Saving data into db using SqlAlchemy, object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to insert some data into a database, unfortunately it fails and does not save, I suspect my data is structured in a bad way. The data gets printed nicely (1 title, link and date per object) in process_item before attempting to save "print(title, link, date)", however it fails to save it. Title, link and date each holds 1 string...

**Thankful for your help**

**Error:**

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "spider.py", line 63, in <module>
    presstv = spider_html(presstv_url, presstv_extract_item, presstv_xpath, presstv_pipeline)
  File "spider.py", line 58, in spider_html
    pipeline.process_item(extract_function(element), None)
  File "/Users/dav/Projects/python/news/pipeline.py", line 76, in process_item
    if session.query(Presstv).filter_by(link=item['link']) == None:
TypeError: 'Presstv' object is not subscriptable"
```

**Code**

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from models import Nordfront, Presstv, db_connect, create_presstv_table
import json



class PresstvPipeline(object):
    """Pipeline for storing scraped items in the database"""
    def __init__(self):
        """
        Initializes database connection and sessionmaker.
        Creates deals table.
        """
        engine = db_connect()
        create_presstv_table(engine)
        self.Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)


    def process_item(self, items, spider):

        session = self.Session()


        for title, link, date in zip(items['title'], items['link'], items['date']):

            print(title, link, date)
            item = Presstv(title = title, link = link, date = date)


            if session.query(Presstv).filter_by(link=item['link']) == None:
                try:
                    session.add(item)
                    session.commit()
                    logger.info('Item saved')
                except:
                    session.rollback()
                    raise
                finally:
                    session.close()

                return item
```

**Model:**

```
class Presstv(DeclarativeBase):
    """Sqlalchemy deals model"""
    __tablename__ = "presstv"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column('title', String)
    description = Column('description', String, nullable=True)
    link = Column('link', String, unique=True)
    date = Column('date', String, nullable=True)
    created_at = Column('created_at', DateTime, default=_get_date)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use:

```
if session.query(Presstv).filter_by(link=item.link) == None:
```

as `item` is now a object from SQLAlchemy. This probably happened because you are using `items['link']` a few lines before that but `item` is now an instance of that class so you should access its values using `.link`.